# Handling task definition changes when using CodePipeline to deploy to Amazon ECS

Tags: amazon-ecs, aws-codepipeline

I am using CodePipeline to deploy my ECS service. The CodePipeline connects to Github at the source stage, CodeBuild at the build stage and uses Amazon ECS(Not blue green) to deploy to ECS. I have my `taskdef.json` file committed into Github with environment variables etc. How do I handle updates to my taskdef.json being used by CodePipeline deploy stage? I don't see any option to specify the path to the task definition. I am generating the `imageDefintions.json` file but changing environment variables, for example, looks like a manual task definition update to me at the present.

P.S: If you suggest I use CodeDeploy, I cannot because the ECS service is a service that doesn't need a load balancer.